# Removing empty lines from csv file using Python

Tags: python

I am creating a code that will calculate means of the first 5 rows. However, I cannot think of the way to remove a row if it initially was left empty. Here is the sketch of my code. Sorry if it is primitive,I am still a novice.Thanks!

```
import csv
import statistics
with open('Test.csv') as file:
 data=csv.reader(file,delimiter=',')

 sample1=[]
 sample2=[]
 sample3=[]
 sample4=[]
 sample5=[]
 #I was trying to do something like that but then
 #I receive error message that states that statistics.mean requires at least
 #one value.
 #(for row in data:
    #if row:
        #some=row[1])
 for row in data:

    sp1=row[0]
    sample1.append(sp1)
    sample1=[int(x) for x in sample1]
    sp2=row[1]
    sample2.append(sp2)
    sample2=[int(x) for x in sample2]
    sp3=row[2]
    sample3.append(sp3)
    sample3=[int(x) for x in sample3]
    sp4=row[3]
    sample4.append(sp4)
    sample4=[int(x) for x in sample4]
    sp5=row[4]
    sample5.append(sp5)
    sample5=[int(x) for x in sample5]

 mean1=statistics.mean(sample1)
 mean2=statistics.mean(sample2)
 mean3=statistics.mean(sample3)
 mean4=statistics.mean(sample4)
 mean5=statistics.mean(sample5)
 print(mean1)
 print(mean2)
 print(mean3)
 print(mean4)
 print(mean5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner way of doing it:

```
import csv
import statistics

fromFile = []
with open('sample.csv','r') as fi:
    data=csv.reader(fi,delimiter=',')
    first = True
    for row in data:
        if first:
            first = False
            continue
        if not filter(lambda a: a != '', row):
            continue
        fromFile.append(row)
print statistics.mean([int(item[1]) for item in fromFile])
```

Sample CSV file:

```
name, age
bob,9
rachel,90


,,,,
joe,5
```

Comment: You can even skip comparing to an empty string and leverage Python's truthiness mechanism: `if not row.strip():`

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately I am receiving an error which states that 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. This time it says that  list index is out of range.I was thinking that if I input something like this: data = [row for row in data if row != []] (the idea is that I want to remove all empty rows before going into the for loop) but it still has the same error.